# PHP/SQL, Anomalous behaviour with Assoc value

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am making an SQL query through PHP, and I need to retrieve a field called **shipdate** carrying a *Datetime* object.

Now,

```
$databk=sqlsrv_fetch_array( $qbk, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If I write

```
print_r($databk);
```

following is the output:

> Array ( [prc_iva] => 22.00 [clientCode] => 000003 [artCode] =>
>   LEODRG-1104 [quantity] => 3 **[shipdate] => DateTime Object ( [date] =>
>   2014-04-23 00:00:00** [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Belgrade
>   ) [cod_um] => PZ [cod_art] => LEODRG-1104 [des_articolo] => SCATOLE
>   C/FIORI PORCE [cod_immagine_small] => LEODRG-1104PIC.jpg [prz_listino]
>   => 2.750000)

As you can see, we have the **shipdate** field here.

But, if I write

```
echo $databk['shipdate'];
```

the output is null/(blank string).

Now, here's ***why it gets creepy***:

I used *exactly the same query* on another page. To be honest, I just copy-pasted the query so even the variable names are same. It works on the other page, but here is the problem on this page.

I need to resolve this as soon as possible. 
Thanks for your help, if any, in advance.

**Ask for any additional information, if required. I shall be quick**

**EDIT2**: Apparently, I couldn't echo date. But here's the new question. Why could I do it on another page. In fact, I still do. Why does it work at one place and not at the other?

Comment: Show your full code, please

Comment: @AlmaDo That's 400 lines. I am hoping it's a good idea. Fine, I just did!

Comment: You can't echo a Date, you have to format the date.

Comment: @xmarston I said it works on another page. Why, then?
See edit.

Comment: @Cheeku What are you getting in the other page?

Comment: @xmarston I am using **echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($databk['shipdate']));** on the other page but that returns '1970-01-01' on this page, meaning a null string for PHP

Comment: @Well, the solution given by Kristiyan should work.

Comment: @xmarston It did. See edit. But that keeps me curious. Why can I do something on one page and not on other?

Comment: @Cheeku, I think you have defferent select for both pages or other differentiations.

Comment: @Cheeku Do you store the date as this page? Like a DateTime object?

Comment: @Kristiyan I copied the SELECT so nope.

Comment: @xmarston Nope. I just put it like text '2014-03-02'. It automatically converts it to a Date Time Object. I dunno why.

Comment: @Cheeku I think the sqlsrv_fetch_array function has something to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stored in datebase DateTime object. Not a clear date stamp. You can try with this:

```
$date = $databk['shipdate'];
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

I preffer and suggest to store in datebase only clear date. If you need help please show insert query with variables.